# What is the value of $2x+3y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

> What is the value of $2x+3y$ if
>
> $x+y=6$ & $x^2+3xy+2y=60$ ?

My trial:
from given conditions: substitute $y=6-x$ in $x^2+3xy+2y=60$
$$x^2+3x(6-x)+2(6-x)=60$$
$$x^2-8x+24=0$$
$$x=\frac{8\pm\sqrt{8^2-4(1)(24)}}{2(1)}=4\pm2i\sqrt2$$
this gives us $y=2\mp2i\sqrt2$
we now have $x=4+2i\sqrt2, y=2-2i\sqrt2$ or $x=4-2i\sqrt2, y=2+2i\sqrt2$

substituting these values i got
$2x+3y=14-2i\sqrt2$ or $$2x+3y=14+2i\sqrt2$$

But my book suggests that $2x+3y$ should be a real value that I couldn't get.
Can somebody please help me solve this problem? Is there any mistake in the question.?

Thank you.

Comment: I get the same answers you do, for what that's worth.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a typo ($y$ instead of $y^2$), we restore

$$\begin{cases}x+y=6,\\x^2+3xy+2y^2=(x+y)(x+2y)=60,\end{cases}$$ then

$$2x+3y=\frac{60}6+6.$$

Comment: Yes, I think you caught the error in the question there should be $2y^2$ term instead of $2y$ in second equation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems correct to me

$$x^2+3x(6-x)+2(6-x)=60\iff x^2+18x-3x^2+12-2x-60=0$$
$$\iff-2x^2+16x-48=0\iff x^2-8x+24=0\implies x=4\pm2i\sqrt2$$

Answer (score 0):

we get
$$x^2+3x(6-x)+2(6-x)=60$$
simplifying we obtain
$$-2x^2+16x-48=0$$
or
$$x^2-8x+24=0$$
can you solve this?
you will get
$$x_1=4+2\sqrt{2}i$$
or
$$x_2=4-2\sqrt{2}i$$ and
and
$$y_1=2-2\sqrt{2}i$$
$$y_2=2+2\sqrt{2}i$$ so $x+y=6$

Comment: Is this wrong?  Isn't OP correct?

Comment: sorr i have forgotten to type the $60$, corrected!

Comment: This is exactly the equation that the OP solved correctly, isn't it?

Comment: yes indeed that is